# How to shut down windows closing applications automatically, but having the chance to save unsaved changes

Tags: windows, windows-8, shutdown

When I shut down my PC I usually have roughly 50 application instances open with unsaved pending changes, and roughly 100-150 that can be closed immediately.

Before Windows 8 shutting down the PC started closing the applications and whenever it encountered one with a pending save it showed me the save dialog to which I had very little time to respond, after which I was forced to either terminate the process or abort the shutdown. The situation sucked, as I was forced to initiate the shutdown several times as I went through the dialogs.

With Windows 8 things are even worse. As soon as you initiate the shutdown you are shown a useless screen where you can't do anything except see a list of the applications pending a save showing up as "Not Responding" and your only choices are to forcefully terminate them (without saving) or abort the shutdown.

This leaves me manually closing all the open applications which is a very annoying and long process, taking up to 10 minutes.

Is there a way to tell the PC to shut down which shuts down all apps without pending saves but lets me have a chance to respond to the save dialogs, shutting off the PC when I am done?

Comment: you can't break an egg and hope for it to stay whole if you boil it. if you decrease the timeout for apps to be terminated chances are your changes wont be saved in time, thus leading to you losing work/changes made.

Comment: Can use a small utility to close all applications giving time for save dialogs.  An example is Close All http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/close-all.html

Comment: 150 open apps? Is it an instance of the same app?

Comment: Some are, mostly a lot of apps with many instances each @Tiberiu. Especially notepad is the biggest problem.. i use it to take temp notes. Anyways Brian I've been using the program you suggested and it's great. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: You are taking temporary notes? Then why do you the need to save them? Since you have so many notes, why not use an application designed for "temporary notes? I am now sure there are better ways to fix your "problems", and they have nothing to do with fixing the way Windows shuts down.

Comment: @Tiberiu: I don't need to save them, but if I choose "Force Shut Down" then *any* application quits without being able to save, including programs like Visual Studio where I usually do want to save the changes. I like notepad for temporary notes, and I'm finding CloseAll working well.

Comment: The way I see it, you are asking for the computer to make decisions for you. Just save your work before shutting down, and close each app manually. How often do you shut down anyways?

Comment: @Tiberiu: I just want the computer to tell each open app to gracefully exit, so that the ones that need saving show the save dialog and the ones who don't close. No decisions needed. It's the equivalent of manually clicking the "X" button on each open window and nothing more.

Comment: Any time you have done enough work that you don't want to have to do it again, then SAVE it. Period. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Windows sends an END message to all open applications. It does not necessarily send to all open application at the same time. If one application is holding the queue, then the behaviour you have described fits this scenario.

For example, if you click cancel in one Notepad, Windows will not send the message to the other notepads, and they will never even display an unsaved changes dialogue. If you click cancel the semi transparents screen, the same thing happens, as you described.

The best solution would be to write your own utiilty little program to send a bunch of open applications an end message at the same time, without forcing them to exit.

Right now, you can open Task Manager, go to the Applications tab, order by name, shif+select or ctrl+select the apps you want to close and click End task (this is the equivalent of clicking the X button, only you can do it to many programs at once).